# What does accuracy mean under render audio?

Tags: rendering, export, audio

I was exporting the audio of a VSE project, and under *Render > Render audio...* there's an *Accuracy* option that starts at `1024` by default.

The hover box says it's sample accuracy and that it's important for animation, but I'm still confused about what it refers to, and what exactly is being improved or worsened if the value is changed.

I tried exporting with accuracy set to `1024` and then `1`, and the difference I noticed is that the latter takes much longer, but ends up with a file that is almost the same size (barely smaller) than the file that was output from the former setting.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation alone, I would think that it affects how the audio is treated before encoding, which would explain the difference in processing time with equal final file size.

The operator called by this menu entry is [bpy.ops.sound.mixdown()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.sound.html#bpy.ops.sound.mixdown), which doesn't give more information about this setting, but whose name makes me more inclined to think it being more about the process of down mixing than encoding.

I looked up the source code of the operator here:

[blender/sound_ops.cc at main - blender - Blender Projects](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/src/branch/main/source/blender/editors/sound/sound_ops.cc#L328)

I am not familiar with C language, but I don't see how "accuracy" is used in the operator besides just being declared as existing. So I am really unsure of what it does - and perhaps it does nothing, right now.

To check if it even does anything, I tried to use the operator on a sample project with two audio tracks to mix down, with accuracy at 1, 1024, 4096 and 8192 with the default lossless Flac encoding settings. Things I noted:

- I didn't get a difference in processing time (though that could be due to my test being only 250 frames long)
- Equal output file size
- The resulting spectrograms are all 100% identical (subtracting the bigger accuracy ones to the one at 1 accuracy gives a full black result), showing there's no difference:

[image]
*(Note: I had to compress the picture quite heavily to be able to post it here, so much so that it might look like the spectrograms don't match. But that's only due to compression. The original PNGs do match.)*

So... Maybe it doesn't do anything anymore?

Comment: Interesting... it seems that the accuracy parameter is passed into a function that uses it to set the buffer size. I'm not sure exactly how that affects accuracy, but one guess I have in mind is that it might add blank data if there are multiple samples to write and each one doesn't necessarily line up with the end of the buffer.